# How to set opfunc to a lambda function?

Tags: functions

I've found it's common to set [`opfunc`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'opfunc') in this manner:

```
nnoremap <Leader>r :set opfunc=<SID>my_function<CR>g@
```

With Vim8 supporting lambda functions, is it possible to now set `opfunc` to a lambda function? The following cursory try did not work:

```
:set opfunc={-> "test" }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `operatorfunc` is a option. A option can only have the types boolean (on/off), number or string (see `:help options`). So you can't assign a lambda to an option.

Also the documentation `help 'operatorfunc'` says

> This option specifies a function to be called by the g@ operator.

My interpretation of "specifies" is "names".

I had a look at the code (function `op_function` in `normal.c`). It calls a vim script function by name.

So the answer is: No

Comment: You're implying that lambdas are not functions? From the [Vim manual](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-lambda): A lambda expression creates a new unnamed **function** ...

Comment: @Roxy See update

Comment: I suppose it's also not possible to use a funcref in this spot, even `let Q=function("Bar')`, `set opfunc=Q` though `call Q()` works.

Comment: @Mass Correct. Its a String option, so you can only set a name.

Comment: don't ever do this!: `let Q = {->execute('quit')} | let &opfunc=get(Q,'name')` :)